# Can we use functional component and react hook with ag-grid table?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-hooks, ag-grid-react

I have error when I use ag-grid and react hook in one time. Can I solve this problem?
I have problem like "gridApi.paginationGoToNextPage is not a function".

```
  const onBtNext = () => {
    setTestVar(5);//this is var that defined via react hook, if I not delete this, I will have error
    gridApi.paginationGoToNextPage()
    console.log(gridApi.paginationGetTotalPages())
  }
```

This code work perfect if I not use react hook, but I neeed in it

Comment: try with [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), put the gridApi in that. like this: `useEffect(() => { gridApi.paginationGoToNextPage() })`

Comment: @MayankShukla I try this solution but I have same error(

Answer (score 0):

Try storing gridApi using Ref in functional component like below:

```
    const gridApi = useRef(null);

    const onGridReady = params => {
         gridApi.current = params.api;
    };

    const onBtNext = () => {
        setTestVar(5);
        gridApi.current.paginationGoToNext();
    }
```